# Bigcommerce customer/current.jwt invalid when accessed within PHP curl

Tags: php, api, curl, bigcommerce

I'm trying to generate current login user **token** based on the cookie I have after login using /customer/current.jwt endpoint. I can generate the code if I access the store url on the terminal or via postman. But when it is time to place it within my code, it always returns invalid unless I change the app_client_id which I cannot do because other part of the system requires it to be part of the token.

Here is the code snippet converted from postman

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://<storeurl>/customer/current.jwt?app_client_id=<appid>",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cookie: SHOP_SESSION_TOKEN=3sogin7ro74v87viga4d8jhiha;"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

My curl command works:

```
curl 'https://<storeurl>/customer/current.jwt?app_client_id=<app id>' --header 'Cookie: SHOP_SESSION_TOKEN=3sogin7ro74v87viga4d8jhiha;'
```

I tried adding **Pragma:no-cache** as header but it didn't work.
I cannot think of other work around to generate the token and use it programmatically inside my application.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

TIA

Comment: It seems like you're passing your cookie from the FE to a backend PHP application. Why don't you just fetch the token on the FE with JavaScript, and pass that token to your backend application? That's how this API is intended to be used.

Comment: @NathanBooker as far as I wanted to, I'm getting the token with in curl because the app I'm working on is an external app which requires the token to communicate with 3rd party app installed within BigCommerce. Their app requires the current.jwt token signed with their app_client_id which makes it complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make an API request to get the Customer Login link. You will need to encode a token, attach it to the end of a url, and then navigate to that url.

**Encode a hash**

If you have are working on the server side then you can run `composer require firebase/php-jwt` from the command line to install the JWT composer package. This will allow you to properly encode your token. You will also need a way to create a uuid. I would recommend to run `composer require ramsey/uuid` from the command line so that you can properly generate a uuid. Here is a sample:

```
$token = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode([
'iss' => {CLIENT_ID},
'iat' => time(),
'jti' => \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString(),
'operation' => 'customer_login',
'store_hash' => {STORE_HASH},
'customer_id' => {CUSTOMER_ID}
]);
```

**Attach the token to the end of your url**

If your store url is `https://example.com` then you will need to create a url string that looks like this `https://example.com/login/token/{$token}`. Append the $token from the first step to the end of the url as mentioned.

**Now navigate to this url**

Bigcommerce will automatically log in the customer who is referenced by the `customer_id` in the first step.

If you'd like to reference the documentation then [click here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/customers/customer-login-api). If you like to see some sample code then [click here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/blob/master/src/Bigcommerce/Api/Client.php#L421).

Comment: thank you for your response but what I need it the token generated by https://example.com/customer/current.jwt where it checks the current login session to generate a new token to be use by other app.